# Is the function complex differentiable or even holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am working on the following problem:

Let $f(z) = (\bar{z})^2$.  For what values of $z_0$ is $f$ complex differentiable or even holomorphic?

My solution:

$f'(z_0) = lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(z_0+h)-f(z_0}{h} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{2z_0\bar{h}}{h}+\frac{\bar{h}^2}{h}$

So then this tells me that is not complex differentiable anywhere and therefore it is not holomorphic anywhere?

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

Note that if $z=x+iy$, then 
$$
\left( \overline{z}\right)^2 =(x-iy)^2 = x^2-y^2-2ixy
$$
Letting $u(x,y)=x^2-y^2$ and $v(x,y)=-2xy$, you should verify that the Cauchy-Riemann equations are only satisfied if $x=y=0$. Thus $f$ is only complex differentiable at $z_0=0$.

Comment: As just a comment on the terminology: I think holomorphic (or analytic) is usually reserved for cases when $f$ is complex-differentiable in a _neighborhood_ of a point rather than only at the point itself.

Comment: @SouparnaP Yes you are right! Essentially if the C-R equation are satisfied only in one point, that means that the function is complex differentiable at that point. I am editing, thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

$f(z) = f(x+iy) = (x-iy)^2 = x^2 - y^2 - 2ixy$

Since $\displaystyle \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 2x \neq - 2x = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$, Cauchy-Riemann theorem shows this is not holomorphic.

I don't know about your approach, I don't really get why the last limit shouldn't exist (at least not as an immediate fact)

Comment: You were right about the derivative, but Cauchy Riemann equations aren't those. Note that according to your statement $z \to z$ is not holomorphic ($u=x, v=y$, and $0 \neq 1$)

Comment: Yes my bad! you got only wrong the derivative ! I am not the downvoter btw. I've deleted my comment since you correct the derivative.

Comment: Np, thank you for noticing the mistake

Answer (score 0):

$f(z) = (\bar z)^2 = (x-y i)(x-y i) = (x^2-y^2) + (-2xy)i$
$\frac d{dx} Re(f(z)) = 2x$
$\frac d{dy} Im(f(z)) = -2x$
The requirement for a function being holomorphic is that $\frac d{dx} Re(f(z)) = \frac d{dy} Im(f(z))$. That is not the case, so the function is not holomorphic.

Comment: Oh my bad. A little too late.